# Log4j2 : change filename dynamically in RollingFile Appender

Tags: java, date, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I am using log4j2 and a rolling file appender, to roll file based on size and time. here is my config file and a dummy example:

log4j2.xml

```
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" filename="log/${date:dd-MM-yyyy-HH}/currentRoll.log"   filePattern="log/%d{dd-MM-yyyy-HH}/Roll-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{ISO8601}{GMT} %p %c{1.c} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>

        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="3KB"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>

    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d{ISO8601}{GMT} [%t] %-5p %c{1}: %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </Console>

</Appenders>

 <loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Async"/>
    </Root>
 </loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and my dummy logging class:

```
public class Helloworld extends TimerTask {
private static final Logger logger=LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");


@Override
public void run(){
    logger.info("fake info message");
    logger.info("another fake info message");
 }
}
```

My problem is that my current log (currentRoll.log) file is in the folder that was first created when
the program started. I would need it to be in the last. So for example if I start running the program at 1pm on November 25th, 2014 , and at 3pm I want to look at the current logs they would not be in the 25-11-2014-15 folder but in the 25-11-2014-13 folder.

My guess is that the `${date:dd-MM-yyyy-HH}` is not resolved dynamically. I tried polling for automatic recofniguration using monitor interval:

```
<Configuration status="info" name="MyApp" packages="" monitorInterval="5">
```

and using the "$$" as in : `$${date:dd-MM-yyyy-HH}` but this gives me the following error:

```
"2014-11-26 17:22:27,143 ERROR Unable to create file log/${date:dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm}/currentRoll.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I know that log4net has a datePattern parameter that allows to resolve this problem, but I could not find an equivalent for log4j2.

Any suggestion on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date used for the rolling appender is determined when it creates the rolled logfile. Or, in log4j terms, "the resolution of the whole RollingFile element is deferred until a match occurs". That is, the {date} property is interpolated at the specified resolution only when it goes to roll the file.

The $$ facility can be used for many properties, though I'm not sure if {date} is one of those. I have a feeling it is not, in which case the filespec being made will contain "${date...}" literally. This might be root of the error you are seeing.

I have tried, in the past, to use system properties via "$${sys:someProperty}" in appender file names (where you can set a default in the "Properties" section) but you have to make sure that you set the System property in question before you invoke the Logger at all, or you *might* end up with rolled files that only use the default value.

See the Log4J docs on [property substitution](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) for what I'm talking about.

At the end of the day, my own solution will probably require implementing the logger programmatically so I can change the root name of the log file, and abstract end-user-friendly properties into a simple property file instead of dumping an XML file on them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're saying implement a logger, but wouldn't it be enough to implement an Appender?

Comment: Correct, I am talking about the Appender. But, what I've found is that it is tricky to change the name of the output file in an appender. You can use $${sys:somePropName} and set somePropName in your code BEFORE the logger is invoked at all. In your case, I'm unsure {date} can be substituted later via $$ (not all properties are supported) and even so, the variables are evaluated when a "match" occurs. This may or may not be what you want. It may be easier to programmatically implement the whole Logger in Java code instead of configuring the existing logger context.

Comment: To answer your question, I don't know if you can implement only the appender(s) programmatically, and use the default root Logger provided out of the box. I would assume not, but I haven't gone down that path yet.

Comment: Hi, I am going thorugh the same problem. Can we have a proper solution ?